# how to make an ON and OFF button

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying make something like this:

[image]

If I click on the off side, the pink circle on the right should disappear and appear on the left.
But at the moment, am struggling with the html markup.

HTML:

```
<div class="inner-box">
 <p>off</p>
 <div class="rectangule">
   <p class="left"></p>
   <p class="right"></p>
  </div>
    <p>on</p>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.inner-box{
  display: flex;
}
.rectangule {
  background-color: red;
  width: 80px;
  height: 24px;
  margin: 0 10px;

  .left{
    float: left;
  }
  .right{
    float: right;
  }
  .left,
  .right{
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -3px;
  }
}
```

[This is where I got so far.](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/QGKqbG)

How can I do it as it is in the picture I posted above?

Hope you can help

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on how to code these, did you have a look at them? :)

Comment: First off you should only need a single "circle", and it should slide from left to right and vice versa. Then all your code needs to do is give the circle a left or right class.

Comment: Rewrite your html. You should be using a checkbox and a label for this, so you can do a :checked on the input (for on) and different css for off.

Answer (score 3):

See this DEMO using HTML and CSS to create **Toggle Switch**

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label><br><br>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

<sub>[Reference from W3Shools](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_switch)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://codepen.io/nendhruv/pen/gLwGoP) is a similar iOS toggle button

Hope this helps.

```
<div class="item">
        <p>Today Summary</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_today_summary" name="" value="">
        <div class="toggle">
            <label for="toggle_today_summary"><i></i></label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The link goes to a 404page

Comment: Thanks..I'll make a few tweaks from there to make it look the way I'd like.